# Swift2 SpriteKit twitter share error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I am trying to implement sharing via twitter and the function looks good but when the button is clicked i get an error in my GameScene.

at this line line: 
    `let skView = self.view as! SKView`
*Error: Thread 1 SIGARBT*

Ive been stuck on this the entire day. Any help would be great

```
var vc = GameViewController()
vc.showTweetSheet() // button click causes error ^ ^ ^
```

//GameView

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

func showTweetSheet() {
    let tweetSheet = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
    tweetSheet.completionHandler = {
        result in
        switch result {
        case SLComposeViewControllerResult.Cancelled:
            //Add code to deal with it being cancelled
            break

        case SLComposeViewControllerResult.Done:
            //Add code here to deal with it being completed
            //Remember that dimissing the view is done for you, and sending the tweet to social media is automatic too. You could use this to give in game rewards?
            break
        }
    }

    tweetSheet.setInitialText("Test Twitter") //The default text in the tweet
    tweetSheet.addImage(UIImage(named: "TestImage.png")) //Add an image if you like?
    tweetSheet.addURL(NSURL(string: "http://twitter.com")) //A url which takes you into safari if tapped on

    self.presentViewController(tweetSheet, animated: false, completion: {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("Whatever", object: nil)
    })
}

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView //ERROR HAPPENS HEREE (ONLY ON CLK
        skView.showsFPS = false 
        skView.showsNodeCount = false

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        scene.size = self.view.bounds.size

        skView.presentScene(scene)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "ThisIsTheMethodName", name: "Whatever", object: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You way does not work, you are creating a new instance of GameViewController rather than accessing the current GameViewController

```
 var vc = GameViewController() // This creates new instance of GameViewController
```

The best way to do access the current gameViewController is usually using delegation or NSNotificationCenter rather than getting a reference to it.

You could also put your shareSheet function into GameScene and show it on the rootViewController.

```
  self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(tweetSheet...
```

As an alternative may I suggest you make a reusable helper so in your future games it will be much easier to reuse this code.

I use protocol extension in Swift 2 to achieve this. Create a new swift file, call it something like SocialHelper and add this code (just copy the 2 methods and change it to twitter, the code is the same)

```
  import SpriteKit
  import Social

 /// URLs
 private struct URL {
          static let iTunesApp = NSURL(string: "Your iTunes app link")
          static let facebookApp = NSURL(string: "Your Facebook app link")
          static let facebookWeb = NSURL(string: "Your Facebook web link")
  }

   /// Text strings
  private struct TextString {
       static let shareSheetText = "Can you beat my score"
       static let error = "Error"
       static let enableSocial = "Please sign in to your account first"
       static let settings = "Settings"
      static let ok = "OK"
  }

  /// Social
  protocol Social {}
  extension Social where Self: SKScene {

  /// Open facebook
 func openFacebook() {
      guard let facebookApp = URL.facebookApp else { return }
      guard let facebookWeb = URL.facebookWeb else { return }

      if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(facebookApp){     
          UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(facebookApp)
     } else {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(facebookWeb)
   }
}

  /// Share to facebook
  func shareToFacebook() {

      guard SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook) else {
             showAlert()
             return
       }

     let facebookSheet = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
     facebookSheet.completionHandler = { result in

           switch result {

           case .Cancelled:
               print("Facebook message cancelled")
              break

          case .Done:
              print("Facebook message complete")
              break
          }
      }

      let text = TextString.shareSheetText //
      facebookSheet.setInitialText(text) // share sheet text for Facebook will not work anymore if app is installed
    facebookSheet.addImage(Your UIImage)
    //facebookSheet.addURL(URL.iTunesApp) // seems to mess up image, Facebook only

        self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(facebookSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }

   /// Show alert
  private func showAlert() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: TextString.error, message: TextString.enableSocial, preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: TextString.ok, style: .Cancel) { _ in }
          alertController.addAction(okAction)

       let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: TextString.settings, style: .Default) { _ in

          if let url = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
             UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
         }
     }
     alertController.addAction(settingsAction)

   self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
      }
  }
```

Now in the scene you want to show the shareSheet you simply conform to the proctocol

```
  class YourScene: SKScene, Social {....
```

and call the method as if it is part of the scene itself.

```
 openFacebook()    // opens app or safari
 shareToFacebook()
```

Hope this helps